# Jquery If, else if, else condition not running at a moment

Tags: html, jquery

I need to validate field, with more than 6 field and running at multiple step.

And I got issue when I try this code :

```
button#stepOne.onclick = function (e) {
    $("label").text('');
    if ($("#email").val() == '') {
        $("#email").addClass("warning");
        $("#email-error-req").text('Email need to fill in!');
        error = true;

    } else if (!emailReg.test($("#email").val())) {
        $("#email").addClass("warning");
        $("#email-error-req").text('Please use email format!');
        error = true;

    } else if ($("#fullname").val() == '') {
        $("#fullname").addClass("warning");
        $("#fullname-error-req").text('Fullname need to fill in!');
        error = true;

    } else if ($("#class").val() == '') {
        $("#class").addClass("warning");
        $("#class-error-req").text('Class need to fill in!'');
        error = true;

    }  else {
        $("label").text('');
        if (!validateform()) {
            return false;
        }
        formnumber++;
        updateform();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

When validation running (after user click button), the validation not running at a moment, but running 1 by 1.
Example, when email field and class field are empty, the warning massage only show at Email Field, not showing at class field.

I need that validation running in the same time, anyone can help? please

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: `emailReg` is undefined as per your code. Also, this line has a double single quote in the last which makes the whole code non-working. `$("#class-error-req").text('Class need to fill in!');` . Is it a Typo mistake or do you really have that in your code too? Multiple issues

Comment: Pseudocode:
If 2>1, write "greater";  else write "smaller"

it only shows "greater", why it does not show "smaller" at the same time?

Comment: `} else if ($("#fullname").val() == '') {` -> remove the `else` as this (roughly) means "only run this if the previous lines didn't run".

Answer (score 0):

You can push the errors in an array and then if there exists any element in an array that means error occured,
instead `if...else if...else if` simply use `if` multiple times.

**pseudo code**

```
var arrErrors = [];
$("label").text('');
if ($("#email").val() == '') {
    $("#email").addClass("warning");
    $("#email-error-req").text('Email need to fill in!');
    arrErrors.push("error1");
    error = true;

}
if (!emailReg.test($("#email").val())) {
    $("#email").addClass("warning");
    $("#email-error-req").text('Please use email format!');
    error = true;

    arrErrors.push("error2");
}
if ($("#fullname").val() == '') {
    $("#fullname").addClass("warning");
    $("#fullname-error-req").text('Fullname need to fill in!');
    error = true;
    arrErrors.push("error3");

}
if ($("#class").val() == '') {
    $("#class").addClass("warning");
    $("#class-error-req").text('Class need to fill in!');
    error = true;
    arrErrors.push("error4");

}

if(arrErrors.length>0){
    //got errors! handle by iterating arrErrors
}
```